# countless gods from antiquity and thinking about them

Tags: hadith

One day i was thinking about the countless false gods that are worshiped. I imagined pictures of Jesus Christ, countless statues of Hinduism and Buddhism. I even imagined several small nude statues (Phallic Gods) from antiquity. Have i commited any sin for doing this? If so what is the level of that sin?  Kufr?   Major?  or Minor?

Comment: Why do you consider it to be a sin? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Bismi Allah Ar Rahman Ar Rahim.

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

All Perfect Praise be to Almighty God,

and prayers and peace be upon the Messenger of Allah and his family and companions,

> God Almighty said : ("Yet among the people are those who take other
>   than God as equals to Him. They love them as the love of God. But
>   those who (truly)believe have greater love for God. If only the wrongdoers
>   would realize, when they see the torment; that all power is God’s, and
>   that God is severe in punishment.")(Surat Al-Baqarah:165)
>
> And Said : ("Say (O Mohammad), “I am only a human being like you, being inspired
>   that your god is One God. Whoever hopes to meet his God, let him work
>   righteousness, and never associate anyone with the worshiping of his
>   God.”")(Surat Al-Kahf:110)
>
> And Said : ("And God Says, “O Jesus son of Mary, did you say to the
>   people, `Take me and my mother as gods rather than God?'“ He says,
>   “Glory be to You! It is not for me to say what I have no right to. Had
>   I said it, You would have known it. You know what is in my soul, and I
>   do not know what is in Your soul. You are the Knower of the
>   hidden.")(Surat Al-Ma'ida:116)

Having said that,

Peace be upon those who follow guidance,

It depends on the way you thought of those so-called "gods", 
What was your way of thinking of them, do you think that they have the ability to help you or harm you? or did you just think of how could a human being in the 21st century still thinks that those statutes and other stuff deserve worshiping.

if it is the first answer : that's major shirk (association) and you have to repent from it immediately and abandon returning to such thinking

if it is the second answer : you are fine and there is no sin in thinking of people (wrongdoers) worshiping rocks and sculptures, as long as you are not thinking that there is nothing wrong with it.

and God knows best.